# How do I track changes and store calculated content in Nermalization?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
lives_with_owner_no from    until   under_the_name
1                   1998    2002    1
3                   2002    NULL    1
2                   1997    NULL    2
3                   1850    NULL    3
3                   1999    NULL    4
2                   2002    2002    4
3                   2002    NULL    5
```

It's [the Nermalization example](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/20-Nermalisation.html), which I guess is pretty popular.

Anyway, I think I am just supposed to set up a dependency within MySQL for the `from` pending a change to the `lives_with` table or the `cat_name` table, and then set up a dependency between the `until` and `from` column.  I figure the owner might want to come and update the cat's info, though, and override the 'from' column, so I have to use PHP?  Is there any special way I should do the time stamp on the override (for example, `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`)?  How do I set up the dependency within MySQL?

I also have a column that can be generated by adding other columns together.  I guess using the cat example, it would look like:

```
combined_family_age family_name
75                  Alley
230                 Koneko
132                 Furrdenand
1,004               Whiskers
```

Should I add via PHP and then input the values with a query, or should I use MySQL to manage the addition?  Should I use a special engine for this, like MemoryAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the nermalization example on two counts.

1. There is no cat entity in the end. Instead, there is a relation (cat_name_no, cat_name), which in your example has the immediate consequence that you can't tell how many cats named Lara exist. This is an anomaly that can easily be avoided.
2. The table crams two relations, lives_with_owner and under_the_name into one table. That's not a good idea, especially if the data is temporal, as it creates all kinds of nasty anomalies. Instead, you should use a table for each.

I would design this database as follows:

```
create table owner (id integer not null primary key, name varchar(255));
create table cat (id integer not null primary key, current_name varchar(255));
create table cat_lives_with (
  cat_id integer references cat(id),
  owner_id integer references owner(id),
  valid_from date,
  valid_to date);
create table cat_has_name (
  cat_id integer references cat(id),
  name varchar(255),
  valid_from date,
  valid_to date);
```

So you would have data like:

```
id | name 
 1 | Andrea
 2 | Sarah
 3 | Louise

id | current_name
 1 | Ada
 2 | Shelley

cat_id | owner_id | valid_from | valid_to
     1 |        1 | 1998-02-15 | 2002-08-11
     1 |        3 | 2002-08-12 | 9999-12-31
     2 |        2 | 2002-01-08 | 2001-10-23
     2 |        3 | 2002-10-24 | 9999-12-31

cat_id | name     | valid_from | valid_to
     1 | Ada      | 1998-02-15 | 9999-12-31
     2 | Shelley  | 2002-01-08 | 2001-10-23
     2 | Callisto | 2002-10-24 | 9999-12-31
```

I would use a finer grained date type than just year (in the nermalization example having 2002-2002 as a range can really lead to messy query syntax), so that you can ask queries like `select cat_id from owner where '2000-06-02' between valid_from and valid_to`.
As for the question of how to deal with temporal data in the general case: there's an excellent book on the subject, "Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL" by Richard Snodgrass ([free full-text PDF distributed by Richard Snodgrass](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf)), which i believe can even be legally downloaded as pdf, Google will help you with that.

Your other question: you can handle the combined_family_age either in sql externally, or, if that column is needed often, with a view. You shouldn't manage the content manually though, let the database calculate that for you.

Comment: Wallen, your example is actually exactly the same as the Nermalization example.  I just took _only_ the third table from the page linked to.  One of the components of the question is: 'what's a good method to use if I want my table to be finer grained'?  "In SQL" and "externally" form an oxymoron.  Can you please clarify?  Also, thanks for the reference.  I'll start looking there.

Comment: Also, +1 for `integer references cat(id),`.  Thank you.

Comment: Trying to answer my own questions, here.  I'm guessing you mean there's an appreciable difference between handling calculated values like `combnied_age` or `combined_duration` via an external programming language and handling such values via SQL's built-in functions....

Comment: Well, a view is written in SQL, too, so what i meant was: you can do the aggregation with the query as in `select sum(age), family_name from person group by family_name`, or you can say `create view family_ages as select sum(age) age, family_name from person group by family_name` so you can then query this with a simple `select age, family_name from family_ages`

Comment: And, yeah, doing the aggregation in an external programming language is the third option, and often the worst.

Comment: The temporal graining is actually an interesting design issue, and i really have to refer you to Snodgrass for an in-depth discussion. Sometimes you prefer timestamps and make valid_to of one entry equal to valid_from of the next. And sometimes, as i did in the answer, you want a granularity (here Day) and have one valid_to+1 equal the next valid_from. It's a tradeoff between ease of query (using select where between is very convenient) and ease of definition (the constraints you need to ensure integrity get more complicated).

Comment: Could I take that query and put it into a column, somehow, or do I need to use a view?

Comment: That's pretty much what a view is: a (virtual) table whose columns are derived from other tables. You can select from a view just the same way you can select from a table.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks for all the follow-up help.  Maybe I will come back with the product.  Again, thank you very much, wallen.